# Remix js localstorage alternative for server side

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsx, remix.run

I have a remix application to act like frontend.
I load data from my backend and for some data I need to load it only once and reuse it on different pages.
In previous frontend we used localstorage but here is server side which returns me `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

```
import {LoaderFunction} from "@remix-run/node";
import authenticator from "~/services/auth.server";
import Layout from "~/src/Layout";
import {fetchData} from "~/services/fetch.service";

export let loader: LoaderFunction = async ({request}) => {
    const user = await authenticator.isAuthenticated(request, {failureRedirect: "/login",});

    const configs = await fetchData('GET', request, 'api/configs/all')
    .then((response) => {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(async error => {
        await authenticator.logout(request, {redirectTo: "/login"});
    });
    try {
        localStorage.setItem('parameters', configs);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
    return {
        user: user,
        request: request
    };
};

export default function DashboardPage() {
    const data = useLoaderData();

    return (
        <Layout user={data?.user} request={data.request}>

        </Layout>
    );
}
```

I need the config to be accessable at any time, it's not usefull if I need to load it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `localStorage` on the server-side, since it is first set on the client. You could use cookies since they are accessible on the server-side.

Comment: Yeah switched to use Cookies, still isn't the best. What another storage I can use?

Comment: Perhaps if you are storing some small chunks of data, you could use `localStorage`, and if you will get an error that it's not defined you should add a check: 

`if (typeof window !== 'undefined'` { // do stuff with localStorage}. Also you could take a look at [Sessions](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#sessions)